# Incorrect boundingBox on NMAMapView for certain zoom levels with 3D projection

Tags: ios, here-api, here-ios

If I zoom my `NMAMapView` completely out so that you can see the earth globe (`NMAMapViewMinimumZoomLevel`) a call to `NMAMapView`s boundingBox property does return the following coordinates for all the top* / bottom* properties:

```
po self.hereMapView.boundingBox?.topRight
▿ Optional<NMAGeoCoordinates>
  - some : <NMAGeoCoordinates: 0x2828bde00; latitude = -90.000000; longitude = 0.000000; altitude = -340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000>

self.hereMapView.boundingBox?.topLeft
▿ Optional<NMAGeoCoordinates>
  - some : <NMAGeoCoordinates: 0x2828bca20; latitude = -90.000000; longitude = 0.000000; altitude = -340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000>

// ...
```

This is also the case for some zoom levels above. This does not seem correct to me, is this a bug in Here SDK?

**Edit**: This seems to be only a problem with the 3D projection, in the 2D projection at the lowest zoom level we do get valid coordinates

Comment: Which version of the HERE mobile SDK are you using?

Comment: It's HEREMaps 3.11.2

Comment: Are you able to use the latest release which is 3.14 to test if the same issue still persists? You can download it from your account on developer.here.com

Comment: Because of our deployment target I can only go up to 3.13.3 and the issue still exists here unfortunately

Comment: Thanks for the info. We are looking into it and will get back to you soon.

Comment: I checked the latest HERE SDK version and get the same results. Looks like this behaviour has always been the same.
Bounding box is rectangular area in a geographic coordinate system.
Please note [top/bottom]/[right/left] are NMAGeoCoordinates. It is not possible to set invalid lat/log. Values outside of [-90, 90] or [-180;180] will be clamped to that range. Do you expect it to be some invalid values or valid ones but different for top and bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the update in the question (valid Bounding box in 2D Projection) and comments from @dashchak ,this is expected behavior,The bounding box is a rectangle which would be capped to a value different from the bounds of a rectangle.

From [Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMAMapView.html#%2Fc:objc(cs)NMAMapView(py)boundingBox) :

> The boundingBox of the map is the smallest possible NMAGeoBoundingBox
>   which contains all of the map area currently visible on the screen. If
>   the map is in 2D view (zero tilt), the boundingBox should (nearly)
>   exactly coincide with the bounds of the screen rect. If the map is in
>   3D view, the visible screen area is a trapezoid in geographical space
>   (the visible area is wider at the top of the screen than at the bottom
>   due to perspective). Thus, the bounding box will contain some area
>   that is not actually visible on the screen in this case.

Comment: I agree with the documentation. "If the map is in 3D view, the visible screen area is a trapezoid in geographical space (*the visible area is wider at the top of the screen than at the bottom due to perspective*). Thus, the bounding box will contain some area that is not actually visible on the screen in this case." What I get when the whole globe is in sight however is a bounding box with 4 coordinates (-90, 0) for each of it's corners. So that would mean the visible bounding box' width and height is 0. Can you explain to me how this is correct behaviour?

Comment: Not trying to be snarky here, appreciate the response thank you.

Comment: In general, bounding box are intended to be used with Mercator projection to approximate the spherical/ellipsoid shape of earth to a 2D rectangle, when totaly zoomed out and a whole spherical/ellipsoid shape of earth is shown, this approximation does not make much sense hence the coordinates are capped to the default values. You can try switching to a Mercator projection(NMAProjectionTypeMercator) in NMAMapView to check if the behavior is more as per your expectation.

Comment: In 3.15 SDK, bounding box will be nil if any of screen corners can not be projected on the map view.